# Ruby on rails || current_user results to Nill, because of added current_employee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I've created an app where a user can create a sub-user(employee).

I'm trying to add current_employee to my session helper but by doing so it causes current_user to result zero.

How can u achieve creating a new current_employee without hindering current_user

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

    # Logs in the given employee.
  def log_in(employee)
    session[:employee_id] = employee.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

    # Remembers a employee in a persistent session.
  def remember(employee)
    employee.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:employee_id] = employee.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = employee.remember_token
  end

    # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

      # Returns the employee corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_employee?(employee)
    employee == current_employee
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in employee (if any).
  def current_employee
    if (employee_id = session[:employee_id])
      @current_employee ||= Employee.find_by(id: employee_id)
    elsif (employee_id = cookies.signed[:employee_id])
      employee = Employee.find_by(id: employee_id)
      if employee && employee.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in employee
        @current_employee = employee
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
    !current_employee.nil?
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def forget(employee)
    employee.forget
    cookies.delete(:employee_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
       forget(current_user)
      session.delete(:user_id)
      @current_user = nil
      elsif (employee_id = session[:employee_id])
      forget(current_employee)
      session.delete(:employee_id)
      @current_employee = nil
    end
  end

    # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.original_url if request.get?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the problem is what you think it is.

Firstly, you should check the conditional statements for `current_user` and `current_employee` methods. It appears that you are not correctly using comparison operators. i.e. `if (user_id = session[:user_id])` is actually assigning user_id, rather than comparing the values, **=** should be **==**

Reference:

- http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html
- http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-if
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Comparable.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but i though your solution solved the problem, but it didn't. 
The cause is the def log_in(user) session[:user_id] = user.id end I'm trying to add the session[:employee_id]=employee.id. How can i achieve this?

Comment: It appears you have two 'log_in' methods, one will override the other. You should either rename the second, or combine the two methods, and simply assign either employee.id or user.id depending on a conditional statement.

Comment: How can I imply both in the same one? I've tried def log_in(user, employee), but it gives me an error. So does && and or

Comment: If you are adding additional arguments or renaming the method you would also need to change the code where the method is being called. If you merge, you could consider keeping just the one argument, say log_in(user) then in the method check to see what type of object is being passed, ie is it a user or employee record and assign the session attr accordingly. But this seems to be a bit of a smell and I would question the overall design here and would say it is also worth looking into other ways to handle multiple types of users authenticating.